# How to pass -Yrepl-class-based to "sbt console"

Tags: scala, sbt

How do I pass `-Yrepl-class-based` to `sbt console`?  Using scala 2.13 and sbt 1.2.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set REPL specific options this way:

```
Compile/console/scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Yrepl-class-based")
```

You can either set it in your `build.sbt` or directly in the sbt shell:

```
sbt 'set Compile/console/scalacOptions += "-Yrepl-class-based"' console
```

Comment: Note that involving `Seq` isn't strictly necessary, `+= "..."` instead of `++= Seq("...")` will work too